# Periodic motion(s) on a torus

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, geodesics, variational-calculus

I recently came across the Lyusternik-Fet theorem concerning closed geodesics on a compact manifold.

For simplicity of description, take the 2-torus, and imagine it represents the configuration space of a double pendulum.
For every pair of integers $m,n$ (where $m$ represents the number of rotations done by the fist link and $n$ by the second), there exist a periodic motion that on such torus traces a closed geodesic.

A way in which the Theorem is presented is, e.g.:

> For energy $E > max(U)$ and $(m, n) ∈ \mathbb Z^2$, there exists a
>   periodic motion with this total energy for which the first segment of
>   the double pendulum rotates $m$ times and the second $n$ times.

Which to me sounds like that *for every* value of the total energy $E$ (provided it's just bigger than the maximal value of the potential energy $U$) I could get a periodic motion *with arbitrary* $m$ and $n$, which seems absurd.

What I haven't understood?